# Python, documentation strings within classes

Tags: python

How do I print documentation strings within classes

For functions i can do this:

```
def func():  
    """
     doc string
    """


print func.__doc__
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with a class

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        doc string
        """

i = MyClass()  
print i.__doc__
```

This doesn't work. It only prints out `None`.
Am writing a text game and I want to use the doc string as an instruction to the player without using the `print` command

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `None` because the class does not have a docstring. Try adding one:

```
class MyClass(object):
    """ Documentation for MyClass goes here. """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        doc string
        """

i = MyClass()  
print i.__doc__ # same as MyClass.__doc__
```

Comment: Ok. so the doc strings goes directly into the class and not inside the __init__ func. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You defined a doc string for the method `MyClass.__init__` not `MyClass`:

```
print i.__init__.__doc__
```

Put the doc string for the class after the class declaration:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ''' MyClass ... '''
```

And there is always:

```
help(i)
```

To get the class and method doc strings in a single document.